# MongoDB count occurances of a substring in a collection

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Hello I'm a MongoDb beginner. I have a database of a IRC chatlog. The document structure is very simple

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("000"), 
    "user" : "username", 
    "message" : "foobar foobar potato idontknow", 
    "time" : NumberLong(1451775601469)
}
```

I have thousands of these and I want to count the number of occurrences of the string "foobar". I have googled this issue and found something about aggregations. I looks very complicated and I haven't really found any issue this "simple". I'd be glad if someone pointed me in the right direction what to research and I wouldn't mind an example command that does exactly this what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any built-in operator to solve your request.

You can try this query, but it has very poor performance:

```
db.chat.find().forEach(function(doc){
    print(doc["user"] + " > " + ((doc["message"].match(/foobar/g) || []).length))
})
```

If you could change your `message` field to array, then we could apply `aggregation`...

**EDIT:**

If you add array of splitted words into your entry, we can apply aggregation

> Sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569bb7040586bcb40f7d2539"),
    "user" : "username",
    "fullmessage" : "foobar foobar potato idontknow",
    "message" : [ 
        "foobar", 
        "foobar", 
        "potato", 
        "idontknow"
    ],
    "time" : NumberLong(1451775601469)
}
```

> Aggregation. We create new entry for each array element, match given word (foobar, in this case) and then count matched result.

```
db.chat.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$message"},
    {"$match" : {"message" : {"$regex" : "foobar", "$options" : "i"}}},
    {"$group" : {_id:{"_id" : "$_id", "user" : "$user", "time" : "$time", "fullmessage" : "$fullmessage"}, "count" : {$sum:1}}},
    {"$project" : {_id:"$_id._id", "user" : "$_id.user", "time" : "$_id.time", "fullmessage" : "$_id.fullmessage", "count" : "$count"}}
])
```

> Result:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("569bb7040586bcb40f7d2539"),
        "count" : 2,
        "user" : "username",
        "time" : NumberLong(1451775601469),
        "fullmessage" : "foobar foobar potato idontknow"
    }
]
```

Comment: ok so lets say I reformat the database so it looks like "message": ["foobar", "foobar", "potato", "idontknow"], and then it will work with aggregation? how exactly if you dont mind me asking

Comment: @honzaik. Look my answer. Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: perfect! thank you very much. I think that's it. I'll have to study a bit what every keyword means but that's not a problem, I just wanted to know if its the right path.

Comment: I just realized it returns the count of the given word but only in the one document. But if I want to sum all the "count" fields up so it return just one object with all the counts in all documents summed up?

Comment: nevermind I just changed the _id field in $group to null and it seems to work now

Comment: Yes, you can group by fields that you want. Keep playing, if you have any trouble, write here, se try to find a solution...